# how to change the title bar of SlidingMenu

Tags: android, slidingmenu

i dont know how to change the title bar of the slidingmenu,like the icon,the backgroundcolor or image, is there a way to use my own layout file?  I have used sherlock,
i try this：

```
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v1 = inflator.inflate(R.layout.titleview, null);((TextView)v1.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("hello title");
    this.getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v1);
```

but it not work as i want

Answer (score 0):

simply `setTitle(int ResID)` in Activity's `onCreate` method.

Comment: setTitle method is just for the text,but i want to change the icon and  the backgroud image of the title bar

Comment: try to combine slidingMenu with ActionBarSherlock and then view this page  http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html